# Co-prime binomial coefficient

Tags: prime-numbers

A number 'r' is prime if and only if  $\binom{r-1}{k} \equiv(-1)^k \pmod r$

Since 'r' is a prime and it gives non-zero remainder by dividing $\binom{r-1}{k}$ .

So  $\binom{r-1}{k}$ and 'r' are co-primes

If a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>3</sub>,..........,a<sub>r-1</sub> are  coprimes to r  .

Then

Is $\binom{r-1}{0}$a<sub>0</sub>+$\binom{r-1}{1}$a<sub>1</sub>+$\binom{r-1}{2}$a<sub>2</sub>+......+$\binom{r-1}{k}$a<sub>k</sub>+......+$\binom{r-1}{r-1}$a<sub>r-1</sub>

coprime to r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let $r=3,a_1=4$ and $a_0=a_2=5$ then $a_k$ is coprime to $r$, but
$$
5\binom20 +4\binom21+5\binom22=18=r^22\;.
$$